# please help me in solving the below error

Tags: python

below is the error details

bias = ord(password[position % password_length])

Indentation error = expected an indented block

```
   1.
      '''crypt module
   2.

   3.
      Contains a simple function, "crypt", that will both encrypt and decrypt a string
   4.
      of text by XORing it with a password or phrase.'''
   5.

   6.
      import StringIO
   7.

   8.
      def crypt(text, password):
   9.
      '''Encrypts or decrypts a string of text.
  10.

  11.
      text: any string
  12.
      password: the word or phrase you want to encrypt/decrypt with'''
  13.

  14.
      old = StringIO.StringIO(text)
  15.
      new = StringIO.StringIO(text)
  16.
      password_length = len(password)
  17.

  18.
      for position in xrange(len(text)):
  19.
      bias = ord(password[position % password_length]) # Get next bias character from password
  20.

  21.
      old_char = ord(old.read(1))
  22.
      new_char = chr(old_char ^ bias) # Get new charactor by XORing bias against old character
  23.

  24.
      new.seek(position)
  25.
      new.write(new_char)
  26.

  27.
      new.seek(0)
  28.
      return new.read()
  29.

  30.
      def _file_test():
  31.
      '''A testing function'''
  32.

  33.
      str1 = '''A list of quotes from Grade School Essays on the History of Classical Music:
  34.
      "J.S. Bach died from 1750 to the present"
  35.
      "Agnus Dei was a woman composer famous for her church music."
  36.
      "Refrain means don't do it. A refrain in music is the part you better not try to sing."
  37.
      "Handel was half German, half Italian, and half English. He was rather large."
  38.
      "Henry Purcell is a well-known composer few people have ever heard of."
  39.
      "An opera is a song of bigly size."
  40.
      "A harp is a nude piano."
  41.
      "A virtuoso is a musician with real high morals."
  42.
      "Music sung by two people at the same time is called a duel."
  43.
      "I know what a sextet is but I'd rather not say."
  44.
      "Most authorities agree that music of antiquity was written long ago."
  45.
      "My favorite composer is opus."
  46.
      "Probably the most marvelous fugue was between the Hatfields and the McCoys."
  47.
      "My very best liked piece is the bronze lullaby."'''
  48.

  49.
      plain_text_name = 'Music101.txt'
  50.
      encrypted_text_name = 'Music101.enc'
  51.

  52.
      # Save the string as a normal text file
  53.
      file_out = open(plain_text_name, 'w')
  54.
      file_out.write(str1)
  55.
      file_out.close()
  56.

  57.
      # Let's use a fixed password for testing
  58.
      password = 'Cold Roses'
  59.

  60.
      # Encrypt the text file
  61.
      file_in = open(plain_text_name)
  62.
      file_out = open(encrypted_text_name, 'wb')
  63.
      file_out.write(crypt(file_in.read(), password))
  64.
      file_in.close()
  65.
      file_out.close()
  66.

  67.
      # Encrypted file shows a hot mess
  68.
      file_in = open(encrypted_text_name, 'rb')
  69.
      print(repr(file_in.read()))
  70.
      print('-' * 80)
  71.
      file_in.close()
  72.

  73.
      # Decrypt the recently encrypted text file and print it
  74.
      file_in = open(encrypted_text_name)
  75.
      print crypt(file_in.read(), password)
  76.
      file_in.close()
  77.

  78.
      # Run tests when this file is run as a program instead of being imported
  79.
      if __name__ == '__main__':
  80.
      _file_test()
```

Comment: It sounds like Python is complaining because you got the indentation wrong somewhere in your code, but the code you pasted has no indentation. Please correct your formatting so that it matches what you've actually got (and get rid of the pointless numbers) and then someone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what was wrong. I formatted the code and it seems to work...

Comment: @AON You've asked 8 questions over the past few months and accepted no answers. This is frowned upon here at Stack Overflow. Please take a little time reading the FAQ (it's linked at the top of the page). Then go back to your old questions and tick the best answer in each as explained in the FAQ.

Comment: Also, all your questions are titled "please help". You don't have to *ask* for help here. Just ask the question. A question title should give a subject matter expert an immediate idea of what your problem and guide other people as to whether it is something they can answer. The detail is then in the question. You will get better answers to your questions this way.

Answer (score 3):

Remove those line numbers, and fix those indentations. Your code is unusable when it's unindented, but here's a working version with formatting:

```
'''crypt module

Contains a simple function, "crypt", that will both encrypt and decrypt a string

of text by XORing it with a password or phrase.'''

import StringIO

def crypt(text, password):
  '''Encrypts or decrypts a string of text.



  text: any string

  password: the word or phrase you want to encrypt/decrypt with'''



  old = StringIO.StringIO(text)
  new = StringIO.StringIO(text)
  password_length = len(password)


  for position in xrange(len(text)):
    bias = ord(password[position % password_length]) # Get next bias character from password

  old_char = ord(old.read(1))
  new_char = chr(old_char ^ bias) # Get new charactor by XORing bias against old character

  new.seek(position)
  new.write(new_char)

  new.seek(0)

  return new.read()



def _file_test():
  '''A testing function'''



  str1 = '''A list of quotes from Grade School Essays on the History of Classical Music:
  "J.S. Bach died from 0 to the present"
  "Agnus Dei was a woman composer famous for her church music."
  "Refrain means don't do it. A refrain in music is the part you better not try to sing."
  "Handel was half German, half Italian, and half English. He was rather large."
  "Henry Purcell is a well-known composer few people have ever heard of."
  "An opera is a song of bigly size."
  "A harp is a nude piano."
  "A virtuoso is a musician with real high morals."
  "Music sung by two people at the same time is called a duel."
  "I know what a sextet is but I'd rather not say."
  "Most authorities agree that music of antiquity was written long ago."
  "My favorite composer is opus."
  "Probably the most marvelous fugue was between the Hatfields and the McCoys."
  "My very best liked piece is the bronze lullaby."'''

  plain_text_name = 'Music.txt'
  encrypted_text_name = 'Music.enc'

  # Save the string as a normal text file

  file_out = open(plain_text_name, 'w')
  file_out.write(str1)
  file_out.close()

  # Let's use a fixed password for testing

  password = 'Cold Roses'

  # Encrypt the text file

  file_in = open(plain_text_name)
  file_out = open(encrypted_text_name, 'wb')
  file_out.write(crypt(file_in.read(), password))
  file_in.close()
  file_out.close()

  # Encrypted file shows a hot mess

  file_in = open(encrypted_text_name, 'rb')
  print(repr(file_in.read()))
  print('-' * 80)

  file_in.close()

  # Decrypt the recently encrypted text file and print it

  file_in = open(encrypted_text_name)
  print crypt(file_in.read(), password)

  file_in.close()



# Run tests when this file is run as a program instead of being imported

if __name__ == '__main__':
  _file_test()
```

Here's the output:

```
> python test.py

    'A list of quotes from Grade School Essays on the History of Classical Music:\n  "J.S. Bach died from 0 to the present"\n  "Agnus Dei was a woman composer famous for her church music."\n  "Refrain means don\'t do it. A refrain in music is the part you better not try to sing."\n  "Handel was half German, half Italian, and half English. He was rather large."\n  "Henry Purcell is a well-known composer few people have ever heard of."\n  "An opera is a song of bigly size."\n  "A harp is a nude piano."\n  "A virtuoso is a musician with real high morals."\n  "Music sung by two people at the same time is called a duel."\n  "I know what a sextet is but I\'d rather not say."\n  "Most authorities agree that music of antiquity was written long ago."\n  "My favorite composer is opus."\n  "Probably the most marvelous fugue was between the Hatfields and the McCoys."\n  "My very best liked piece is the bronze lullaby.$'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A list of quotes from Grade School Essays on the History of Classical Music:
      "J.S. Bach died from 0 to the present"
      "Agnus Dei was a woman composer famous for her church music."
      "Refrain means don't do it. A refrain in music is the part you better not try to sing."
      "Handel was half German, half Italian, and half English. He was rather large."
      "Henry Purcell is a well-known composer few people have ever heard of."
      "An opera is a song of bigly size."
      "A harp is a nude piano."
      "A virtuoso is a musician with real high morals."
      "Music sung by two people at the same time is called a duel."
      "I know what a sextet is but I'd rather not say."
      "Most authorities agree that music of antiquity was written long ago."
      "My favorite composer is opus."
      "Probably the most marvelous fugue was between the Hatfields and the McCoys."
      "My very best liked piece is the bronze lullaby.
```

Regex and a quick press of the spacebar works wonders ;)

Answer (score 2):

The indentation of a python program is part of its meaning. For example,

```
for i in range(20):
    t = i
    print i
```

prints the numbers 0 through 19, but

```
for i in range(20):
    t = i
print i
```

only prints 19 (Python 2) or gives a variable scope error (Python 3). In the first example, the indentation means that 'print i' is inside the loop; in the second, it is not.

In your given code, lines 18 and 19 look like

```
for position in xrange(len(text)):
bias = ord(password[position % password_length])
```

which is a loop with nothing in it followed by a separate statement. A loop with nothing in it is illegal in Python, and causes the error message.

It should instead be

```
for position in xrange(len(text)):
    bias = ord(password[position % password_length])
```

which iterates along the text to be encoded.

In any case, the crypt() function is much more complicated than it needs to be; it could be replaced by

```
from itertools import izip, cycle

def crypt(text, password):
    """Encrypts or decrypts a string of text.

    @param text:     string, text to encrypt
    @param password: string, encryption key
    """
    return ''.join(chr(ord(t)^ord(p)) for t,p in izip(text, cycle(password)))
```

and test_crypt() can likewise be simplified,

```
import testwrap

def test_crypt():
    """Test the encryption function.
    """

    test_str = textwrap.dedent("""
        A list of quotes from Grade School Essays on the History of Classical Music:
        "J.S. Bach died from 1750 to the present"
        "Agnus Dei was a woman composer famous for her church music."
        "Refrain means don't do it. A refrain in music is the part you better not try to sing."
        "Handel was half German, half Italian, and half English. He was rather large."
        "Henry Purcell is a well-known composer few people have ever heard of."
        "An opera is a song of bigly size."
        "A harp is a nude piano."
        "A virtuoso is a musician with real high morals."
        "Music sung by two people at the same time is called a duel."
        "I know what a sextet is but I'd rather not say."
        "Most authorities agree that music of antiquity was written long ago."
        "My favorite composer is opus."
        "Probably the most marvelous fugue was between the Hatfields and the McCoys."
        "My very best liked piece is the bronze lullaby."
    """)

    pw = 'Cold Roses'
    encrypted = crypt(test_str, pw)
    decrypted = crypt(encrypted, pw)

    if decrypted != test_str:
        print 'Test failed!'
    else:
        print decrypted
```

Comment: Even though the OP is probably not going to accept your answer, you still took the time to write an amazing explanation. +1 for being epicly nice.